# Consolidate 2 IIS6 webservers into one IIS7 webserver

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, migration, msdeploy

I'm trying to consolidate 2 webservers with different sites within into a single new IIS7 web server.

I thought I would be able to do it using msdeploy tool. It doesn't seem to allow multiple sources.

There is anyway to achieve this?