# Consolidate two IIS6 webservers into one IIS7 webserver

Tags: web-server, iis-6, migration, iis-7.5, consolidation

I have two servers each running IIS6 and i need to bring all the siteson BOTH servers into ONE IIS 7.5 server...

i've looked at MSDeploy but i can't find anything to combine two servers into one... thoughts? help? anything?!?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/157889/consolidate-2-iis6-webservers-into-one-iis7-webserver Not that that helps ...

Answer (score 0):

Just deploy all the sites from both servers into the new server. You're not "combining servers", you're putting all the sites from X number of servers onto a new server.

This doesn't cover any issues that would arise from the different IIS versions, dependency on .NET version, etc.

Comment: when i tried to use the msdeploy stuff from MS one server would always over write the previous one thereby never allowing me to fully integrate both servers together.

Comment: Explain your process fully. I'm guessing that you're doing the entire server from both servers. As I suggested, maybe you should simply do all the sites from the first server, and then all the sites from the second server, instead of doing it per-server.